# joomla redirect user after logout

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, logout

I am trying to redirect user after logout , here is my code:

```
$app     = JFactory::getApplication();              
$user    = JFactory::getUser();
$user_id = $user->get('id'); 
$par     = array();
$par['return'] = urlencode(base64_encode('index.php?option=com_teaching&view=parents&layout=cpanel&Itemid=150'));

$app->logout($user_id,Array('return'=>$par['return']));
```

Comment: Any errors occuring?

Comment: no it just logged me out , but i also need to add return url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$app = JFactory::getApplication();

$app->logout($user_id);    
$app->redirect(JURI::base().'index.php?option=com_teaching&view=parents&layout=cpanel&Itemid=150', $error, 'error' );
```

or

```
$app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_teaching&view=parents&layout=cpanel&Itemid=150', false));
```

after logout.

Comment: I have tried this one , but its not come here again to execute next redirect line, $app->logout it logged it and redirect him to login view but i need to add return url ...

Comment: xmm so you try to add something like that at the url &return=aW5kZXgucGhwP29wdGlvbj1jb21fcGl6emFwaWU=' so as controller to decode that.Let me think.

Comment: How about to comment $app->logout and use only redirect instead as follows.$return = base64_encode('index.php?option=com_teaching&view=parents&layout=cpanel&Itemid=150');
$url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&' . JUtility::getToken() . '=1&return=' . $return); and then $app->redirect($url, $error, 'error' );  Something like that

Comment: I saw somewhere that the controller.php will take return value of the object a return url

Comment: Or see this tutorial about login.Suppose will help you http://rselvakumar.blogspot.gr/2012/08/joomla-redirect-after-login.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use **Joomla! Authentication Plugin** and in that plugin you can type your redirection code in `onUserAfterLogout` event.

- Example: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/plugins/authentication/cookie/cookie.php#L281